# Bash completion for cd alias

Tags: bash

I'm using the following function to list the directory contents after changing the current working directory:

```
function c() {
  cd $@;
  ls;
}
```

How can i enable bash directory name completion for the 'c' function so that it also works for directories in $CDPATH?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the completion function of the command `cd` to the function `c`. First determine which completion function the cd command has assigned. In my case:

```
$ complete | grep " cd$"
complete -o nospace -F _cd cd
```

It's the function `_cd`, in my case _cd honours the `$CDPATH` variable. Now set your functions completion function:

```
$ complete -o nospace -F _cd c
```

Now, when typing `c <tab><tab>`, the same suggestions are made as when typing `cd <tab><tab>`

To make it permanent, write the command into your `~/.bashrc`.